# Scroll and fix div elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a web page with a side bar where locates at the left side.

The side bar is now scrollable and have 2 divs in it. The height of 2 divs is bigger than the window's height.

Below is a similar picture of the page. The height of div1 is variable, e.g. the height of div1 is 400~800px depends on how many content is added, and the height of div2 is always 250px.

[image]

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="div1" style="overflow-y:scroll;">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
               ... 
            <li>N</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="div2">
        <div>Constant Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Somehow there is no scroll bar in the div1.

My objective is to fix the div2 at the left-bottom corner and show its all content without scrolling down, and the div1 should be scrollable to see its content.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Both div should be the same height ? The side bar is taking the whole screen height ? Please make reproducible example

Comment: Hi @MaxiGui, the side bar is taking more than the whole screen height.

Comment: please have look to answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use flex for this:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}

/* make sidebar flex and 100% height */
#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
  /* demo only */
  width:200px;
}

#div1 {
  flex-grow: 1;  /* make div1 grow to take remaing space after div 2 hs shown it's contents */
  position: relative;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.scroll {
  /* this just fills your div 1 and then scrolls if it overflows */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

#div2 {
  /* demo only as there is no content, I just gave some height for demo purpose */
  min-height:50px;
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <div id="div1">
    <div class="scroll">
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>N</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>N</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>N</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>N</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>N</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>N</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>N</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>N</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>N</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="div2">
    <div>Constant Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set an height for the scrollable div so:

```
<div id="sidebar">
<div id="div1" style="overflow-y:scroll; height:50vh;">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
           ... 
        <li>N</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="div2">
    <div>Constant Content</div>
</div>
```

i think with this should work

Answer (score 0):

So after you edited your question, I adjusted my answer based on the height you were given.

Side bar will work dynamically:

- the sidebar can grow from 650px till 1050px
- The div1 will grow from 400px minimum till 800px and over, it will use overflow.
- div2 will always make `height: 250px`

Code:

```
    #sidebar{
      min-height: 650px;
      max-height: 1050px;
      width: 20vw;
      display:flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    #div1{
      min-height: 400px;
      max-height: 800px;
      height: auto;
    }
    #div2{
      height: 250px;
    }
```

### DEMO (short text in div1)

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  display:flex;
}
main{
  height: 600vh;
  width: 80vw;
  background:lightblue;
}
#sidebar{
  min-height: 650px;
  max-height: 1050px;
  width: 20vw;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#div1{
  min-height: 400px;
  max-height: 800px;
  height: auto;
  background:orange;
}
#div2{
  height: 250px;
  background:lightgreen;
}
#div1 ul{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <div id="div1" style="overflow-y:scroll;">
      <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
           <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
          
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
        <div>Constant Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
<main>
</main>
```

### DEMO (long text in div 1)

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  display:flex;
}
main{
  height: 600vh;
  width: 80vw;
  background:lightblue;
}
#sidebar{
  min-height: 650px;
  max-height: 1050px;
  width: 20vw;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#div1{
  min-height: 400px;
  max-height: 800px;
  height: auto;
  background:orange;
}
#div2{
  height: 250px;
  background:lightgreen;
}
#div1 ul{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <div id="div1" style="overflow-y:scroll;">
      <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
           <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
          
      </ul>
            <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
           <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
          
      </ul>
            <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
           <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
          
      </ul>
            <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
           <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
          
      </ul>
            <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
           <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
          
      </ul>      <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
           <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
          
      </ul>      <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
           <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
          
      </ul>
            <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
           <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
          
      </ul>
            <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
           <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
          
      </ul>
            <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
           <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
          
      </ul>
            <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
           <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
          
      </ul>
            <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
           <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
             ... 
          <li>N</li>
          
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
        <div>Constant Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
<main>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Pete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64502330/13331155) suggested, but making the sidebar stick and no `min-height`:

```css
html, body {
  height: 200%;
  background: lightblue;
}

#sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#div1 {
  position: relative;
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 105px;
}

.scroll {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

#div2 {
  background: orange;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <div id="div1">
    <div class="scroll">
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>N</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>N</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>N</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>N</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>N</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>N</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>N</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>N</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>N</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    Constant Content
  </div>
</div>
```